# Changing order of calling constructors in class with guest object

Tags: c++, class, constructor

```
class a
{
   object guest;
}

a::a() : guest(required_argument)
{
}
```

The problem is that I need the guest's constructor to be called AFTER creating class' a object. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the reason for `guest` to be constructed *after* `host` is that some functionality of `host` is required in the construction of `guest`. In this case, you can out-source that functionality into a separate class which is constructed before `guest`. Thus

```
class some_interface { /* some abstract functionality needed by guest::guest() */ };

class guest
{
public:
  guest(some_interface const&); // calls pure virtual functions of some_interface
  /* more stuff */
};

class host_interface : public some_interface 
{
  /* implements pure virtual methods of its base */
};

class host
{
  host_interface _interface;
  guest _guest;
public:
  host(...)
  : _interface(...)
  , _guest(_interface)
  {}
  /* more stuff */  
};
```

Note that the following naive implementation will fail

```
class host : some_interface
{
  /* some_data */
  guest _guest;
public:
  host(...)
  : some_data(...)
  , _guest(*this)
  {}
  /* more stuff */
};
```

because `this` is not yet constructed when passed to `guest::guest()`, and the pure virtual functions will be called (I really had this bug once and got the *run-time* error "pure-virtual function called", even though the compiler should have been able to detect this).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep `guest` as an object, no.

If you are free to make it a pointer, you can use lazy initialization for it.

Comment: That's a shame it's not possible, but for sure there are reasons for it. Thanks for answer anyway.

Comment: @user1873947 the reason is that if `object` has a constructor, it's not a POD, so the standard mandates it get initialized.

Answer (score 2):

The real question is *why* do you need `guest`'s constructor to be called after `a`'s constructor?

`guest` is a part of `a`, so having its constructor invoked *after* `a`'s constructor is a **contradiction in terms**: an object is completely constructed only if all of its sub-objects are completely constructed, so completing the execution of `a`'s constructor implies completing the execution of `guest`'s constructor.

Of course, this doesn't mean you cannot just default-construct `guest` during `a`'s construction and assign it a different value after or, if you do not want a `guest` object to be constructed at all during `a`'s construction, to use a pointer (better if smart pointer) for modeling the association between `a` and `object`.

Comment: The a class is main gui class and the guest object is a widget which uses main gui's resources. I declared guest as a std::shared_ptr and I call make_shared in a's constructor and that has done the job.